How have rocket propulsion system designs developed over the years in terms of effectiveness?
I am working on a research project about developing rocket propulsion designs for school. More specifically, I am researching how rocket propulsion designs have changed over the last century, in terms of making it more effective through changes in propellant mix, structural design, shape of the rocket nozzle, pressure system, cooling systems etc. However, I have found little information on this topic, with that information being lacklustre in answering my question and providing a thorough insight. It would be greatly appreciated, if I could get a general overview of my question and some additional directions to studies, articles and credible sources for my study and research question.

Most research assistants get paid.

There are certainly books on this, do you have access to a library?

Here's a starting place, perhaps: https://arstechnica.com/science/2013/04/new-f-1b-rocket-engine-upgrades-apollo-era-deisgn-with-1-8m-lbs-of-thrust/

One starting place is the Scott Manley series "Kerbal Space Programme doesn't teach..." (on YouTube), particularly the ones about nozzles, engine cycles, and propellants. Those should give you some historical overview as well as a good list of individual systems and designs to research for when they were developed and implemented.

It might depend on how you define "effectiveness". There's a question/answer here where "effectiveness" is more narrowly defined as "the cost of delivery of cargo into orbit".

One important point in more recent years is the ability to simulate fluid and gas flow in engines. This has profoundly changed the development of rocket technology especially engines as it is possible to try designs out at little cost and remove most of the major issues before moving on to prototypes. Compare the old Russian N1 hardly any computerized testing to Starship or even Falcon heavy with a vast amount. Have a look here to see what is done and how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYA0f6R5KAI

you might be interested in the different types of rocket engine from simplest to most complex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Owji-ukVt9M

I would also suggest you check out the series of "Know Your Rocket" by the Pressure Fed Astronaut. He's got a great comprehensive breakdown of more recent commercial rocket development and economic history

What level of "School" are you studying at?

While  Ignition is mostly about liquid fuels, it does give a good idea of some of the things that were going on over the big period of development.

Well, some of the changes which I found are:

Ignition in a vacuum
Re ignitable engines
Improved Isp
Better nozzle expansion ratio
More reliable engines
Electric turbopump engines (Rutherford engines that power the electron rocket)
Deep throttling
More efficient combustion cycles
Better fuel
Super chilled cryogenic fuels (SpaceX's Falcon 9 uses super chilled LOX and Kerosene to run its Merlin engines)
More powerful engines


Do you have any evidence to support these claims? Ignition in a vacuum was achieved by Apollo. Same with Re-ignitable engines. The RL-10 engine is among the earliest engine designs (from the 1950s) and has among the highest Isp's ever achieved. Cryogenic propellants were used in the earliest Atlas rockets. The F-1 engine is the most powerful rocket engine ever tested.  How has modern rocket science surpassed these achievements I list?  I think it has, but your answer does not convince.
